Github - how to undo some commits and set specific one as latest
I am making some aplication and made some mistakes during this proccess. I'd like to go back to specific commit from github, download it and then push to github as latest one in order to be able to start from exact point, how can I manage it ?
Tried to clone my repo, then checkout to commit im intrested in and then push it to repo but I guess thats not right way to do it


git reset --hard <Commit Id> - reverts your local repo to state after that commit, --hard option undoes local changes
git push --force-with-lease pushes repo state to remote, note that --force would work as well, however with lease is considered more safe - it is explained here: git push --force-with-lease vs. --force

